How to make a custom shape rug?
I want to make a rug from animal crossing but idk how to do it. I've tried using curves but  I still can't seem to understand that feature well X)
rug pic:


Do you mean that you want to create a rug with the flower shape?

yeah! or at least something similar to the one on the pic

For anyone who is not signed up to Reddit, that link won't work!

You just need to follow the shape with some extrusions, then fill the face, and project the image on the face with an Image Texture?

https://imgur.com/a/xrDqthO <-- I hope this link works
moonboots, yeas thats what I'm trying to do Х)

Extrude a vertex all around the shape of your rug:

Fill with F:

Extrude and scale a bit:

Choose the front view and unwrap with the Project from View option:

Give a material to your object, plug an Image Texture into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF, in the UV Editor place the UV over the image:

If you plan to give a Subdivision Surface modifier add some support edge loops:

